# iOS 8 statusbar rotating twice when rotating phone

Tags: ios, rotation, xcode6, statusbar

So I have seen this for quite a while now but I still wonder why this happens. When your app is in landscape mode and you rotate your phone or simulator on to the other landscape side it appears as if the status bar is clearly rotating twice.  If you don't see this at first try activating slow animatons (⌘T on the simulator). I can see it happening on my iPhone as well.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

[image]

Comment: Probably it's nothing but iOS Simulator lag. Check if the same happens on another device. Also, please give more details. Is your root view controller is using another `UIView` animations?

Comment: If I do this in the simulator with slow animations enabled I can clearly see that the statusbar rotates twice. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 0):

That's nothing but a common iOS Simulator lag. It happens just because of the slow animation mode and you could even send a Bug Report to Apple, but that's nothing but a Simulator lag. Don't worry: This issue will never happen in a recent iOS device. Happy programming!

**EDIT:** Apparently you want deep details. Ok. If your app's rotation animations are faster than iOS standard animations, this should happen because the system probably notices that the app's rotation is not near ready and returns for keeping up the pace. For deep details and possibilities to change these details on the Info.plist file, please look on the [iOS Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/).

Best regards,

Comment: Why does the happen on my iPhone as well?

Comment: Show me a picture. That's not that normal on an iPhone. Also I made an edit on the answer. Look at it.

Comment: Well, Believe me, it happens on the iPhone 6 if tried it on. Have you tried this on your phone?

Comment: Never happened with me outside the iOS Simulator.